# extract rectangular shape id card area from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, adaptive-threshold

I have a hundreds of ID card images which some of them provided below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
(***Disclaimer**: I downloaded the images from the Web, all rights (if exist) belong to their respective authors*)

As seen, they are all different in terms of brightness, perspective angle and distance, card orientation. I'm trying to extract only rectangular card area and save it as a new image. To achieve this, I came to know that I must convert an image to grayscale image and apply some thresholding methods. Then, cv2.findCountours() is applied to threshold image to get multiple vector points.
I have tried many methods and come to use cv2.adaptiveThreshold() as it is said that it finds a value for threshold (because, I can't manually set threshold values for each image). However, when I apply it to images, I am not getting what I want. For example:

[image]

My desired output should look like this:
[image]

It seems like it also includes affine transformations to make the card area (Obama case) proper but I am finding it difficult to understand. If that's possible I'd further extract and save the image separately.

Is there any other method or algorithm that can achieve what I want? It should consider different lighting conditions and card orientations. I am expecting one-fits-all solution given there will be only one rectangle ID card. Please, guide me through this with whatever you think will be of help.

Note that I can't use CNNs as object detector, it must be based on purely image-processing.
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
The code for the above results is pretty simple:

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh_img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,9)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

area_treshold = 1000
for cnt in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > area_treshold:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        print(x,y,w,h)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)


resize = ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=640)
cv2.imshow("image", resize)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**EDIT 2:**
I provide the gradient magnitude images below:
[image]

Does it mean I must cover both low and high intensity values? Because the edges of the ID cards at the bottom are barely noticeable.

Comment: You should show the code you have used and maybe someone could help.

Comment: Try to force better contrast between foreground and background. For example by placing the bright id card in front of a dark background

Comment: @Micka sorry, I didn't get you meant

Comment: Threshold on the cards background color using cv2.imRange(). Get the background color from averaging the 4 corner regions of the image. Permit some amount of tolerance to allow for variations in the background color.

Comment: Please post the images individually. That way we can give you a way that actually works on your original images.

Comment: Please post the thresholded images. In my own work, I have also found *Otsu* thresholding and `cv2.equalizeHist` to be helpful.

Comment: @AnnZen I posted original images

Comment: @nathancy, I hope you could help out here

Comment: @fmw42, did you mean `cv2.inRange()` method? Can you give a simple working example for one image please?

Comment: Yes. cv2.inRange(). It was a typo.  Seems pretty straight-forward. Get a small subsection at each corner. Get the average color of each region. Get the average of the 4 corner averages. Use that as the basic color. Then decrease if for low color (lower) and increase it for high color (upper) for cv2.inRange()

Comment: @bit_scientist have you found solution for this task?